# Add a print button for an iFrame document

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a iFrame that is linked to a out sourced quote on another website. Is it possible to add a print button for the results inside that iFrame?

I have the following code attempt but it's not doing much at all - When the button is clicked, it does nothing

```
<iframe src="https://www.compulife.net/website/1295/quoter.html" width="750 pixels" id="test" name="test" height="750 pixels" frameborder="0" formtarget="_blank"></iframe>

<input type="button" value="Print" onclick="test()" />

<script>
function test {
window.frames["test"].focus();
window.frames["test"].print();
}
</script>
```

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function
    at HTMLInputElement.onclick
```

Is there something that I might be doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: seems typo-- function test() {

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there are two mistakes you are doing the typo error for your function instead of

`test()` you have called just `test` and secondly

> Uncaught TypeError: test is not a function
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

is from the `window.frames["test"].print();` instead of this you can use

`document.getElementById("test").contentWindow.print();`

Even if you managed to clear al this error since you mentioned ***I have an iFrame that is linked to an outsourced quote on another website***  won't get the result because

you are going to end up in an error like this

> SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame

This is because ***You can't access an iframe with different origin using JavaScript, it would be a huge security flaw if you could do it.***

see the workaround at:[SecurityError: Blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25098021/securityerror-blocked-a-frame-with-origin-from-accessing-a-cross-origin-frame)